# How to add dynamic button for each row in quasar table

Tags: vue.js, datatable, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to add buttons for table rows without using a slot. I am trying to push buttons in the column I am sharing bellow:

```
const columns = [
 {
  name: 'name',
  required: true,
  label: 'Member No.',
  align: 'left',
  field: row => row.name,
  format: val => `${val}`,
  sortable: true
 },
 { name: 'short_name', align: 'left', label: 'Short Name', field: 'short_name', 
   sortable:true},
 { name: 'address', align: 'left', label: 'Address', field: 'address', sortable:true},
 { name: 'ward_count', align: 'left', label: 'Ward No', field: 'ward_count', sortable:true},
 { name: 'bed_count', align: 'left', label: 'Bed No', field: 'bed_count'},
 { name: 'entry_by', align: 'left', label: 'Entry By', field: 'entry_by'}
]
```

From Template :

```
<q-table
  title="Treats"
  :rows="rows"
  :columns="columns"
  row-key="id"
  v-model:pagination="pagination"
  :loading="loading"
  :filter="filter"
  @request="onRequest"
  binary-state-sort
>
  <template v-slot:top-right>
    <q-input borderless dense debounce="300" v-model="filter" 
     placeholder="Search">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="search" />
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </template>

</q-table>
```

These buttons should pass current row id as well.

Comment: Can you please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: This should probably be done in the `template` where you have the quasar table. Please add your template code to your question. Probably you need to use [custom rows](https://v0-17.quasar-framework.org/components/datatable.html#Custom-rows).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835380/quasar-qtable-clicking-an-action-button-on-clickable-row

Comment: Please check the template, I have included it in my question :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code from my project, this is how i do it.. let me know if you need more details..

```
   <q-table  row-key="id" title :rows="arrData" :columns="arrColumns"
            v-model:pagination="pagination" :filter="filter" @request="request" binary-state-sort   separator="cell" class="tableStyle outline">
          
 
            <template v-slot:body-cell-your_button_column_name="props">
              <q-td :props="props">
                <q-btn round unelevated color="red" @click="onButtonClick(props.row.id)" label="Your Button Label"></q-btn>
              </q-td>
            </template>
          </q-table>
```

Comment: Please check the template, I have included it in my question :)